# Multiselect hide label container (primeNg)

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I'm trying to get the multiselect dropdown to only show the arrow icon, even if items are selected (i.e., remove the "choose" default label, as well as any selected items).

[image]

Is it possible?

My multi-select code is:

```
<p-multiSelect 
  [options]="cars" 
  optionLabel="brand"
  [style]="{'border': 'none'}">
</p-multiSelect>
```

I tried to hide the label container element...but the label is still showing

```
.ui-multiselect-label {
display:none !important;
}
```

Below is a stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ba5zqd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [Angular style isolation](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/), you have to use the [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) shadow-piercing descendant combinator to modify the CSS styling of a child component:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-multiselect-label {
  visibility: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbkas8) for a demo.

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way to make it so that when the items are selected, the label does not expand?  Right now, with visibility hidden, the label grows in size when more items are selected.  Is the best way to just set a fixed width and height?

Comment: It seems to work when setting a fixed width on the multiselect, as shown in the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbkas8).

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!